# How to highlight text permanently in WebView in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, epub

I am developing an ePUB reader for Android phones.

I can get text copied to the ClipBoard using WebView & ClipBoardManager. But what I really want to do is highlight the selection permanently. I saw some articles. They suggested to get WebView in selection mode & to use JavaScript.

How can I get WebView in selection mode? If I go with JavaScript and get the text modified, can I save those changes applied by the JavaScript permanently in the corresponding ePUB file? If yes then how?

Comment: were you able to get a resolution for this?