# How to highlight text permanently on android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, highlight

I am doing Epub reader and showing book inside android webview.

At present i can highlight text using below javascript

```
public static String Highlightscript = " <script language=\"javascript\">" +

        "function highlightSelection(){" +
        "var userSelection = window.getSelection();" + 
        "for(var i = 0; i < userSelection.rangeCount; i++)"
        + "  highlightRange(userSelection.getRangeAt(i));" +
         "}" +
        "function highlightRange(range){"+
        "span = document.createElement(\"span\");"+
        "span.appendChild(range.extractContents());"+
        "span.setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:block;background:#ffc570;\");"+
        "range.insertNode(span);}"+
        "</script> ";
```

and to when user clicks on highlight i do

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:highlightSelection()");
```

This highlight the text and i also save the highlighted text in local database

but when user reopens the book i want to show the previous highlighted text . How can i achieve this ?

i am trying to find the text when user enters the page(which highlights text by default) by

```
webView.findAllAsync(highlightedText);
```

but if highlighted text was too small like  word "The" , a lot of words will be highlighted .

I already searched on SO , but all questions were unanswered  [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872574/can-we-have-area-selection-feature-on-webview-in-android) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969448/how-to-highlight-text-permanently-in-webview-in-android)

So is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you have to know what part of the webview you want to highlight.  You can't know this just by storing the highlighted text (as you've seen).  The only way to do it is going to involve storing some version of the location of the highlight.

Your answer is in the code you showed for highlighting the text in the first place.

`highlightRange(userSelection.getRangeAt(i));`

Store information from the Range objects.  You'll then need to load this information as you load pages.  Do the equivalent of your `Highlightscript` function, but with the Range information you saved.

**Adding detail in response to comment**

Lookup the Range interface (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range).

When you first highlight the range, you can extract the starting node and offset and ending node and offset information.  Store this in your database.  (How you do that depends on what database you're using.)

Retrieve the appropriate information when you visit the page.  Create Range objects using `document.createRange()` or the `Range()` constructor.  Fill in the start and end information you saved.

Call `highlightRange()` on the Range objects you constructed.

Comment: not worth the bounty but still awarding because i dont want to waste it

Comment: What do you feel is missing from the answer?

Comment: 1.How do i save a location
2.even if i saved some kind of location , how will i rehighlight at that location/range

Comment: Added some steps.  Going further would require more details on your specific implementation.