# Highlight the selected text in webview. [Android]

Tags: android, webview, highlight

I have certain text in the web view. I can select those text . I want to highlight those text but I have no idea how to do it. Anyone having any idea about it, please help! Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to run java script

```
 public static String Highlightscript = " <script language=\"javascript\">" +

    "function highlightSelection(){" +
    "var userSelection = window.getSelection();" + 
    "for(var i = 0; i < userSelection.rangeCount; i++)"
    + "  highlightRange(userSelection.getRangeAt(i));" +
     "}" +
    "function highlightRange(range){"+
    "span = document.createElement(\"span\");"+
    "span.appendChild(range.extractContents());"+
    "span.setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:block;background:#ffc570;\");"+
    "range.insertNode(span);}"+
    "</script> ";
```

and

```
  webView.loadUrl("javascript:highlightSelection()");
```

make sure you enabled javascript

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: thanks. Can you explain me a bit more? this userSelection.rangeCount is this inbuilt function? can you explain this piece of code to me.                             Thanks in Advance

Comment: yes it will be inbuilt function.   when ever you are loading data into webview add the string Highlightscript along with it . and when user clicks highlight button call  `webView.loadUrl("javascript:highlightSelection()");`

Comment: on longPress webview allows to select text. so this userselection.rangecount would know the starting and ending point of the user selection?  Another thing is by on long press i am getting some of the default options like copy,share,search on web . Is there any way to add more options to it or disable these options.?

Comment: yes, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection/22391169#22391169

Comment: @ManoharReddy is it possible to save what the user highlighted? So that the next time he opens the application, the text remains hightlight?

Comment: @RGS check if this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670806/how-to-highlight-text-permanently-on-android-webview .

Answer (score 1):

In Android 4.1(jellybean), WebView.findAll() is deprecated, we should use WebView.findAllAsync instead.

[reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findAll(java.lang.String))

Wish this help:)