# (Android & Ios) Webview select text and highlight

Tags: xamarin, webview, wkwebview

I am developing an reader app on xamarin for android and ios.I have an html page content and I use the webview to show it up.
I want to select the part of text and highligt it.I should be able to store the page so I think if I get the position of selected text I can insert < mark > tag start and end of the text.
Also Should I add an item to the menu that opens after a long press?

I use the webviewrenderer for transparent webview so I can change backgorund and text size.
How can I do this ?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1EJf.png)

Comment: You can try to [get the selected string](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/174965/how-to-get-tapped-selected-text-or-paragraph-from-a-webview-android-ios) and find them. And there are some native solutions you can find if you search like [highlight-the-selected-text-in-webview-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993571/highlight-the-selected-text-in-webview-android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem using [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy).
I added the library and functions and call from app and it works perfectly.
This library adds span tag to selected content and so I can store the highligts.

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).